# Create side bar widget showing list of years as hyperlinks for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, loop, widgets, custom-post-type-archives

I have a WP site using Elementor Pro. I have created a Custom Post Type called "Meeting"

I have created an archive page for "Meetings" using a Loop Grid To display the post thumbnails, a title and a "read more" link.

At the side of this I want an Archive Widget in the side bar to show a list of years (that contain at least one "meeting"). I just want a list of years that when you click on a year it just shows posts for that year.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First, create the custom WordPress widget. This will query all the years that have at least one post for your custom post type "**Meeting**." Save the following code in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
class Meeting_Archive_Widget extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('meeting_archive', 'Meeting Archive', array('description' => 'List Meetings by Year'));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        global $wpdb;
        $query = "SELECT YEAR(post_date) AS `year` FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type='meeting' AND post_status='publish' GROUP BY `year` ORDER BY post_date DESC";
        $years = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        echo $args['before_title'] . 'Meeting Archives' . $args['after_title'];

        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($years as $year) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_post_type_archive_link('meeting') . '?year=' . $year->year . '">' . $year->year . '</a></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
}

add_action('widgets_init', function(){
    register_widget('Meeting_Archive_Widget');
});
```

Next, modify the main Meetings query on your archive page to account for the `year` URL parameter. You could add this code also in your `functions.php`:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function($query){
    if (!is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive('meeting')) {
        if (isset($_GET['year'])) {
            $query->set('year', $_GET['year']);
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is look for the `year` parameter in the URL and filters the `meetings` post type displayed based on that year.

And that's it! I haven't tested the code but in theory that should do the trick for you. If you encounter some issues just adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you mean by create a custom Wordpress Widget. Do I do this in Elementor?